# How can I select a dataframe regarding some conditions over a datetime intervals(24hrs) via a plotting

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, python-datetime

I have plotted a Dataframe over a day and I would like to consider the negative parts (<0) marked in blue when x becomes positive for the first time and when it turns negative for the "first" time too but for a long time.
NB: intervals marked in black although negative cannot be taken into account.
Plots -> [plot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MGNl.png)  [plot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnfX2.png)
here ist my csv file: [csv-file](https://gofile.io/?c=D53yfH)
Any hints !? Thks
here is my approach

```
day_start = datetime.time(00,00,00)

day_end = datetime.time(23,59,59)

day_check = day_start


for col in df:

   for col in range(day_start, day_end):

      df = 0

   while df < 0:

      neg_df = df[(df < 0).all(1)]

      if df > 0:

    break

       day_check += 1 
       .....
```

I don't know how to handle the steps in the second picture

Comment: Already answered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58872052/iterate-over-index-and-define-each-range-as-a-day/58872525?noredirect=1#comment104024309_58872525