# iterate over index and define each range as a day

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, object

my last question didn't find any help/answer and I found another approach and I wanted to know if it's possible to iterate over a column set as index(DateTime with pandas format:

- 2019-05-02 00:03:00
- 2019-05-02 00:08:00
- 2019-05-02 00:13:00
- 2019-05-02 00:18:00
- 2019-05-02 00:23:00
- 2019-05-02 00:28:00
- 2019-05-02 00:33:00
- ...
- )

, so that during the iteration I can specify that the range from 00:03:00 to 23:59:00 is a day
(do something) and so on. I have issues dealing with date objects on pandas.
Thks for your help.

Comment: can you please share a snippet/example of your data?

Comment: Are you looking for `.iterrows()`? Add code, what you have tried so far?

Comment: @Chrisvdberge snippet https://pasteboard.co/IGMaw5i.png
@shaikmoeed yes I have tried .iterrows 
` def filter_by_time(data:pd.DataFrame, day_start:datetime.time(0,0,0), day_end:datetime.time(23,59,59), freq:str = "5min") -> pd.DataFrame:
    valid_times = time_range(day_start, day_end, freq)
    for index, row in data.iterrows():
        for row in valid_times:
            row['x'] == 0
        while ['x'] < 0:
            negative_df = data[(data < 0).all(1)]
        break
        df_filtered = data.loc[[time in valid_times for time in data.index.time]]
        return df_filtered`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a loop on `day` of `datetime` like this.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['SomeDatetime'], index=[0,1,2,3,4,5])
now = datetime.now()
df.loc[0, 'SomeDatetime'] = now + timedelta(minutes = 10)
df.loc[1, 'SomeDatetime'] = now - timedelta(days = 1)
df.loc[2, 'SomeDatetime'] = now + timedelta(minutes = 15)
df.loc[3, 'SomeDatetime'] = now + timedelta(minutes = 20)
df.loc[4, 'SomeDatetime'] = now + timedelta(minutes = 50)
df.loc[5, 'SomeDatetime'] = now + timedelta(minutes = 90)

print("Dataframe\n")
print(df)
print("\nDay Loop\n")
for day in df['SomeDatetime'].dt.day.unique():
    day_value = df[df['SomeDatetime'].dt.day == day]
    print(day_value)
```

This gives you the following result:

```
Dataframe

                 SomeDatetime
0  2019-11-15 09:02:47.784752
1  2019-11-14 08:52:47.784752
2  2019-11-15 09:07:47.784752
3  2019-11-15 09:12:47.784752
4  2019-11-15 09:42:47.784752
5  2019-11-15 10:22:47.784752

Day Loop

                 SomeDatetime
0  2019-11-15 09:02:47.784752
2  2019-11-15 09:07:47.784752
3  2019-11-15 09:12:47.784752
4  2019-11-15 09:42:47.784752
5  2019-11-15 10:22:47.784752
                 SomeDatetime
1  2019-11-14 08:52:47.784752
```

You can do this for `week` and others as well.
**Edit after comment**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['SomeDatetime', 'x', 'y'], index=[0,1,2,3,4,5])
now = datetime.now()
df.loc[0, 'SomeDatetime'] = now + timedelta(minutes = 10)
df.loc[1, 'SomeDatetime'] = now - timedelta(days = 1)
df.loc[2, 'SomeDatetime'] = now + timedelta(minutes = 15)
df.loc[3, 'SomeDatetime'] = now + timedelta(minutes = 20)
df.loc[4, 'SomeDatetime'] = now + timedelta(minutes = 50)
df.loc[5, 'SomeDatetime'] = now - timedelta(days = 30*4)  - timedelta(days = 3)

df['x'] = pd.Series(np.random.randn(6))
df['y'] = pd.Series(np.random.randn(6))

df.set_index('SomeDatetime', inplace=True)

print("Dataframe\n")
print(df)
print("\nDay Loop\n")

for date in df.index.to_series().dt.date.unique():
    print(date)
    day_value = df[df.index.to_series().dt.date == date]
    print(day_value)
    print('\n')
```

Result:

```
Dataframe

                                   x         y
SomeDatetime                                  
2019-11-15 13:38:13.885939 -1.106788  1.496731
2019-11-14 13:28:13.885939 -0.478087 -0.819366
2019-11-15 13:43:13.885939  1.985328  0.841495
2019-11-15 13:48:13.885939  0.915070 -0.065473
2019-11-15 14:18:13.885939 -0.726703  0.404896
2019-07-15 13:28:13.885939  0.669062 -0.543737

Day Loop

2019-11-15
                                   x         y
SomeDatetime                                  
2019-11-15 13:38:13.885939 -1.106788  1.496731
2019-11-15 13:43:13.885939  1.985328  0.841495
2019-11-15 13:48:13.885939  0.915070 -0.065473
2019-11-15 14:18:13.885939 -0.726703  0.404896


2019-11-14
                                   x         y
SomeDatetime                                  
2019-11-14 13:28:13.885939 -0.478087 -0.819366


2019-07-15
                                   x         y
SomeDatetime                                  
2019-07-15 13:28:13.885939  0.669062 -0.543737
```

Does this help?

Comment: Thks man it can help me! is your SomeDatetime set as an index? what I'm trying to do, is to iterate like you did and do some operations in another column of that Dataframe(if you see the link my Dataframe has 3 columns and I want to manipulate the df['x']) corresponding to that day range found and so on for others days!

Comment: something like ...
`for day in df['SomeDatetime'].dt.day.unique():
    day_value = df[df['SomeDatetime'].dt.day == day]
    while df['x'] < 0:
    negative_df = df[(df < 0).all(1)]
        break`

Comment: I have changed my dataframe to have `SomeDatetime` column to be the index. Please see the edited answer.

Comment: Thks ... but I have a question. I have chosen intentionally a range where there are the last 2 periods of a day - a complete day - and the first five periods of the next day to see if could separate them as individual day but didn't work . see attached pic. https://pasteboard.co/IGNkmuR.png
data_01_01 = df.iloc[0:255]

for day in data_01_01.index.to_series().dt.day.unique():
    #print(day)
    day_value = data_01_01[data_01_01.index.to_series().dt.day == day]
    print(day_value)

Comment: Thks could help me.